# How does Docker seemingly "upgrade" the cmd.exe console?

Tags: docker, cmd, console, tty

I'm running a neat Go application that provides an interactive shell with colors, "special" chars, and a normal POSIXey readline experience.

When I run the app directly in `cmd.exe` (on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit 1903), it shows a warning about color support and is slightly degraded (please ignore the errors that might be my machine setup).

```
cmd> bettercap.exe
```

> WARNING: This terminal does not support colors, view will be very limited.

[image]

When I run the same app in `cmd.exe` via Docker, I get a similar degraded experience.

```
$ docker run --rm bettercap/bettercap
```

> WARNING: This terminal does not support colors, view will be very limited.

[image]

When I run the same app in `cmd.exe` via Docker, but with the interactive/tty flags, I get the full Linux shell like experience and capabilities.

```
cmd> docker run --rm -it bettercap/bettercap
```

[image]

What I want to understand (at any level, honestly) is how Docker can seemingly "upgrade" the console's capabilities. As far as I know `cmd.exe` just can't do those things? I am familiar with the articles about the [recent ConPTY upgrades](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/), but I'm not sure I grok it fully or understand how that is or is not in play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker did not "Upgrade" CMD, **CMD allows color, it's up to the executable running in CMD to be coded to send color to the screen.**

Essentially You just told Docker to go ahead and do that.

ie. You can write an executable in say C# that runs on the CLI (CMD), and writes any text in some arbitrary color of your choosing that CMD supports, and it will show up just fine.

For the life of me, I have NO Idea why Microsoft purposely chose not to colorize 99% their own commands in CMD/DOS for the last 30 years.

Although I imagine now it's something they consider a wasted effort at this point, since they did colorize Powershell and are committed to continuing that forward especially now that it supports Linux.

Also Note:

CMD itself allows you to change the FG and BG Color of the entire prompt at one time.

It's also possible to write CMD Scripts which colorize portions of text BG/FG throughout them without changing the entire prompt by a kludge using "FindStr" or VBScript, and PowerShell as well

Comment: Is it possible that the Go application is mistaken, then, when it says "this terminal does not support colors"?

Comment: The "Terminal" refers to Docker.  Putty, Telnet, Cigwin, they are terminals.  CMD is a Shell, like Bash.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction. I'll go read the ConPTY articles again 

Comment: A shell offers access to the operating system to run executables (compiled code/scripts/etc) in any modern OS it generally has a suite of compiled programs and may be a GUI or a CLI.

Comment: @AnthonyMastreen A Terminal is a "Dumb" connection to a remote system.  The term originally refered to remote keyboard/monitor systems that would allow the user to connect to a mainframe, the terminals could do nothing on their own, they just connexted you to the actual compute powwr to pass it commands.  As the PC rose to dominance, this evolved to be programs running on the PC used to connect to the remote system as, why have purpose built hardware  for rhat function wheneverone has a PC or two on their desk.

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean Further, I think in part, you may have a missunderstanding of the relationship between docker and its apps.  The apps run and docker connects to them to allow you to pass commands to the app and return content to you to view.  Docker is acting as a terminal, it does not run the commands, or format the output, the application it connects to does, and that app can run regardless of you being connected to it

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean  A further analogy to help you.  Windows, like CMD, is a shell.  Remote Desktop is a Terminal application (it connects to the windows "Terminal Server" in fact)  any SSH / telnet client is a terminal, and windows also includes a telnet server if you so choose to enable it allowing you to use a telnet client to send it commands and interact wirh it through CLI remotely as if you were running a cmd shell locally to the server, just as RDP connects you to the windows GUI Shell so you can use the remote system as if logged on directly.

Comment: @AnthonyMarstean I had heard about the nee console changes comming, but as you'll note, that is more about making how terminal programs interact easier, less error prone, and faster, without having to kludge an "off screen" session to scrape and write to and then re-display the info to the console.  It also allows full 24bit color directly in the console so long as you re-write your terminal software to utilize them.  That doesn't mean previous software could not write in colors to the cmd console window, just that this is an improvement & makes it more direct, instead of needing work-arounds.